# Allow user to add the php code in wp_mail()

Tags: plugin-development, wp-mail

I have an email triggered like below. I want a user to be able to customize the content.

I want to provide the user to be able to put `esc_html($user->display_name)` somehow may some thing with a text like `{{user_name}}`

```
$body = sprintf('Hey %s, your awesome post has been published!
         See <%s>',
                 esc_html($user->display_name),
                 get_permalink($post)
         );

    // Now send to the post author.
    wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Your post has been published!', $body);
```

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use `str_replace()` to handle a "pseudo" shortcode.  Something like this:

```
$body = sprintf('Hey {{username}}, your awesome post has been published!
    See <%s>', get_permalink($post) );

// Add replacement values to the array as necessary.
$old = array( '{{username}}' );
$new = array( esc_html($user->display_name) );

$body = str_replace( $old, $new, $body );

// Now send to the post author.
wp_mail($user->user_email, 'Your post has been published!', $body);
```

I just worked from what you started with. I'm assuming you're doing something ahead of this to get the `$user` object.  Also, I made the replacement values for `str_replace()` as arrays, so you can add to that as necessary (instead of running it multiple times).